# Possible bug with FourierTransform linearity

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Each component is easily transformed but the sum is not:

```
FourierTransform[f''[x], x, k]
FourierTransform[f'[x], x, k]
```

> ```
> -k^2 FourierTransform[f[x], x, k]
> -I k FourierTransform[f[x], x, k]
> ```

```
FourierTransform[f''[x] + f'[x], x, k]
```

> ```
> FourierTransform[f'[x] + f''[x], x, k] (*!!*)
> ```

---

`LaplaceTransform` behaves correctly:

```
LaplaceTransform[f''[x] + f'[x], x, k]
```

> ```
> -f[0]-k f[0]+k LaplaceTransform[f[x],x,k] + k^2 LaplaceTransform[f[x],x,k] - f'[0]
> ```

Just in case. Win7 V9.0.1.0

As [**acl**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16/acl) has noticed on chat, `Distribute` would be **quick fix** but not sure how stable for more complicated cases:

```
Distribute[ FourierTransform[f''[x] + f'[x], x, k]]
```

> ```
> -I k FourierTransform[f[x],x,k]-k^2 FourierTransform[f[x],x,k]
> ```

Comment: Related: [FourierTransform and Partial Derivatives?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28625/245)

Comment: Just wrote a "shell" for `FourierTransform` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871), which (I think) is a little more stable than the `Distribute` approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find examples where linearity does not apply - it is conditional upon the relevant transforms existing (e.g. for reasons of convergence).  For example

```
expr1 = FourierTransform[f'[x] - f[x], x, k]
(* FourierTransform[-f[x] + Derivative[1][f][x], x, k] *)

expr2 = Distribute@expr1
(* FourierTransform[-f[x], x, k] - I k FourierTransform[f[x], x, k] *)

Block[{f = Exp}, {expr1, expr2}]
(* {0, FourierTransform[-E^x, x, k] - I k FourierTransform[E^x, x, k]} *)
```

Distribution is not valid as the transform of $e^x$ does not exist.  I can therefore understand why this simplification is not enabled by default, though I'm sure that in other areas Mathematica makes assumptions that are far more questionable.

It is arguable that analogy with `LaplaceTransform` would suggest that distribution should take place, though analogy with `Integrate` would lead to the opposite conclusion.  Automatic distribution of `Integrate` would cause problems for many sensible integrands.

In this case, I see the following differences between Fourier and Laplace transforms:

1. Fourier transforms are undefined for a much larger range of
   interesting functions than Laplace transforms, increasing the risk
   that distribution leads to an unexpected result.
2. Applications I'm aware of for Laplace transforms (e.g. solving
   differential equations) almost invariably require distribution over
   Plus. Fourier transforms have a much wider range of uses.
3. Laplace transforms are more "Applied Maths" than Fourier transforms.  Applied mathematicians have different expectations of correctness.

Comment: But `LaplaceTransform` is also conditional (of course looser than `FourierTransform`), while linearity is implemented in it.

Comment: @xzczd Consistency would obviously be nice, though analogies with other functions (e.g. `Integrate`) might lead you the opposite conclusion. In this case, I see the following differences: 1) `FourierTransform` is undefined for a much larger range of interesting functions than `LaplaceTransform` increasing the risk that it leads to an unexpected result. 2) Applications I'm aware of for Laplace transforms (e.g. solving differential equations) almost invariably require distribution over `Plus`.  Fourier transforms have a much wider range of uses.