# Prove linearity of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I'd like to prove the linearity of integration over one real variable ($x$).

```
Integrate[f[x] + b g[x], x] == Integrate[f[x],x] + b Integrate[g[x],x]
```

which I was hoping would return `True`, but doesn't.

I've tried all manner of assumptions (e.g., $b \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$), without success.  Is there a natural way of ensuring $f$ and $g$ are integrable?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40432/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56237/1871

Answer (score 9):

Since this is the Indefinite Integration, the two sides are the sets of functions rather than a single functons.
The `=` actual means that the set of left hand side is equal to the set of right hand side.

```
D[Integrate[f[x] + b g[x], 
   x] - (Integrate[f[x], x] + b Integrate[g[x], x]), x]
```

> `0`

Comment: that's a nifty trick!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**`TransformationFunctions`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html?v=13.2) in order to [**`Distribute`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html) the integration.

```
Simplify[
 Integrate[f[x] + b g[x], x] == 
  Integrate[f[x], x] + b Integrate[g[x], x], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. 
     smthng_Integrate :> Distribute[smthng] &}]
```

> [image: t]

**Edit:** not sure if you are interested in the following

```
replacement = 
  Integrate[x_ + y_, z_] :> Integrate[x, z] + Integrate[y, z];
```

and then

```
(Integrate[f[x] + b g[x], x] /. replacement) == 
 Integrate[f[x], x] + b Integrate[g[x], x]
```

> [image: t]

Comment: This makes me think about applying parity to functions in the case of symmetric intervals; taking advantage of the fact that in the case of odd functions, it's not necessary to integrate.

Comment: @E.Chan-López that's a good and useful point for definite integrals!

Comment: @bmf:  That's neat (thanks)... but if you distribute the integration you're basically *ensuring* the distribution property, not *testing* it... no?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes, indeed. you are right about that. I guess you meant to test if the functions are Lebesque integrable, right? I am unaware of how to go about proving that.